# how to change domain sub domain(laravel website) url?

Tags: laravel

I have created a sub domain through cPanel that is `test.mydomain.com` and its document root is `public_html/test`

I want to access these when i type `test.mydomain.com` but instead i get `If you are the owner of this website, please contact your hosting provider:` error.

but if write `mydomain.com/test` its working. I dont want my sub domains to work like this.

**I want it in test.mydomain.com format.**

public_html/test Contains Laravel Website.

Website hosted on Hostgator.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to point your subdomain in laravel folder

Comment: @Froxz what do you mean Site is working in mydomain.com/test. What do i do to make it test.mydomain.com

Comment: in cPanel change root folder for subdomain

Comment: @Froxz already did. As i mentioned on first line - root is public_html/test

Comment: then is not clear what you are asking, your subdomain is pointed to `test` folder, but laravel index.php located I assume `test/public/index.php` so you sub domain shoud be pointed `public_html/test/public`

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mentioned that moved everything out of public to test main and changed index.php accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131055/discussion-between-phoenix-and-froxz).

Comment: @Phoenix I think you should take a look into your routes/web.php file where you have defined the routes pointing to your sub-domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions.

The problem was not in cPanel. **I had to wait for few hours before sub domain started working as `test.mydomain.com`.** I could access files using `mydomain.com/test`.

After searching I found out that it could work immediately or sometimes take upto 72 hours.